# How to add a 90º angle arrow annotation in a Bokeh figure

Tags: bokeh

I want to add this type of annotation I do with [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) but in a [Bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/index.html) plot:

[image]

Is it possible? I can only find information about [straight arrows](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#arrows).

Answer (score 0):

As of version 2.4.2. Bokeh only supports straight-line arrows.